# Replace a series of asterisk bullet points with a numbered list

Tags: substitute, filetype-markdown, range, markup, counting

Imagine I have the following text:

```
some random stuff
* asdf
* foo
* bar
some other random stuff
```

I want to replace the asterisk bullets with numbers, like so:

```
some random stuff
1. asdf
2. foo
3. bar
some other random stuff
```

How can this be done in vim ?

Comment: Why don't you go for plugins? A similar one is increment.vim in Github

Comment: It is so amazing and cool that everybody made their answers increment the numbers but since Markdown will number them for you why not just make them all `1.`?  So `:%s/^* /1. /` would do it.  That seems like much less work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could try the following command:

```
:let c=0 | g/^* /let c+=1 | s//\=c.'. '
```

---

First it initializes the variable `c` (`let c=0`), then it executes the global command `g` which looks for the pattern `^*` (a beginning of line, followed by an asterisk and a space).

Whenever a line containing this pattern is found, the global command executes the command:
`let c+=1 | s//\=c.'. '`
It increments the variable `c` (`let c+=1`), then (`|`) it substitutes (`s`) the previous searched pattern (`//`) with the evaluation of an expression (`\=`):
the contents of variable `c` concatenated (`.`) with the string `'. '`

---

If you don't want to modify all the lines from your buffer, but only a specific paragraph, you can pass a range to the global command.
For example, to modify only the lines whose number is between 5 and 10:

```
:let c=0 | 5,10g/^* /let c+=1 | s//\=c.'. '
```

---

If you have a file containing several similar lists which you want to convert, for example something like this:

```
some random stuff                 some random stuff                      
* foo                             1. foo                                 
* bar                             2. bar                                 
* baz                             3. baz                                 
some other random stuff           some other random stuff                
                           ==>                                                
some random stuff                 some random stuff                      
* foo                             1. foo                                 
* bar                             2. bar                                 
* baz                             3. baz                                 
* qux                             4. qux                                 
some other random stuff           some other random stuff
```

You can do it with the following command:

```
:let [c,d]=[0,0] | g/^* /let [c,d]=[line('.')==d+1 ? c+1 : 1, line('.')] | s//\=c.'. '
```

It's just a variant of the previous command, which resets the variable `c` when you switch to another list. To detect whether you are in another list, the variable `d` is used to store the number of the last line where a substitution was made.
The global command compares the current line number (`line('.')`) with `d+1`. If they are the same, it means we are in the same list as before so `c` is incremented (`c+1`), otherwise it means we are in a different list, so `c` is reset (`1`).

Inside a function, the command `let [c,d]=[line('.')==d+1 ? c+1 : 1, line('.')]` could be rewritten like this:

```
let c = line('.') == d+1 ? c+1 : 1
let d = line('.')
```

Or like this:

```
if line('.') == d+1
    let c = c+1
else
    let c = 1
endif
let d = line('.')
```

---

To save some keystrokes, you could also define the custom command `:NumberedLists`, which accepts a range whose default value is `1,$` (`-range=%`):

```
command! -range=% NumberedLists let [c,d]=[0,0] | <line1>,<line2>g/^* /let [c,d]=[line('.')==d+1 ? c+1 : 1, line('.')] | s//\=c.'. '
```

When `:NumberedLists` will be executed, `<line1>` and `<line2>` will be automatically replaced with the range you used.

So, to convert all the lists in the buffer, you would type: `:NumberedLists`

Only the lists between line 10 and 20: `:10,20NumberedLists`

Only the visual selection: `:'<,'>NumberedLists`

---

For more information, see:

```
:help :range
:help :global
:help :substitute
:help sub-replace-expression
:help list-identity    (section list unpack)
:help expr1
:help :command
```

Answer (score 9):

Visually select the lines and execute this substitution command:

```
:'<,'>s/*/\=line('.') - line("'<") + 1 . '.'
```

See `:help sub-replace-expression`, `:help line()`, and `:help '<`.

To avoid having to select the lines, backward and forward searches with offsets can be used to specify the substitution range like this:

```
:?^[^*]?+1,/^[^*]/-1s/*/\=line('.') - search('^[^[:digit:]]', 'bn') . '.'
```

See `:help cmdline-ranges`

Answer (score 9):

This only works with a recent Vim version (that has `:h v_g_CTRL-A`):

1. Block-select the list bullets (`*`) and replace them with `0` (cursor is on first `*`):  `Ctrl-v` `j` `j` `r` `0`.
2. Reselect previous block and *increment with counter*: `gv` `g` `Ctrl-a`

... and that's it :)

---

(If you want to have a dot after each number, change 1st step to: `Ctrl-v` `j` `j` `s` `0` `.` `Esc`)

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
:let n = 1 | g/^* /s//\=printf('%d. ', n)/g | let n = n + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also define custom operators

You could map them to the key sequences `'*` and `'#`. The marks `*` and `#` don't exist, so you won't override any default functionality.
The reason to choose `'` as a prefix is to get some kind of mnemonics. You're adding a sign/mark in front of some lines. And usually to go to a mark you use the prefix `'`.

```
fu! s:op_list_bullet(...) abort range

    if a:0
        let [lnum1, lnum2] = [line("'["), line("']")]
    else
        let [lnum1, lnum2] = [line("'<"), line("'>")]
    endif

    if !empty(matchstr(getline(lnum1), '^\s*\d\s*\.'))
        let pattern     = '\d\s*\.\s\?'
        let replacement = '* '

    elseif count(['-', '*'], matchstr(getline(lnum1), '\S'))
        let pattern     = '\v\S\s*'
        let replacement = ''

    else
        let pattern     = '\v\ze\S'
        let replacement = '* '
    endif

    let cmd = 'keepj keepp %s,%s s/%s/%s'

    sil exe printf(cmd, lnum1, lnum2, pattern, replacement)
endfu

fu! s:op_list_digit(...) abort range
    let l:c = 0

    if a:0
        let [lnum1, lnum2] = [line("'["), line("']")]
    else
        let [lnum1, lnum2] = [a:firstline, a:lastline]
    endif

    if count(['-', '*'], matchstr(getline(lnum1), '\S'))
        let pattern     = '\S\s*'
        let replacement = '\=l:c.". "'

    elseif !empty(matchstr(getline(lnum1), '^\s*\d\s*\.'))
        let pattern     = '\d\s*\.\s\?'
        let replacement = ''

    else
        let pattern     = '\v^\s*\zs\ze\S'
        let replacement = '\=l:c.". "'
    endif

    let cmd = 'keepj keepp %s,%s g/%s/let l:c = line(".") == line("'']")+1 ?
                                                \ l:c+1 : 1 |
                                                \ keepj keepp s/%s/%s'

    sil exe printf(cmd, lnum1, lnum2, pattern, pattern, replacement)
endfu

nno <silent> '*     :<C-U>set opfunc=<SID>op_list_bullet<CR>g@
nno <silent> '**    :<C-U>set opfunc=<SID>op_list_bullet
                    \<Bar>exe 'norm! ' . v:count1 . 'g@_'<CR>
xno <silent> '*     :call <SID>op_list_bullet()<CR>

nno <silent> '#     :<C-U>set opfunc=<SID>op_list_digit<CR>g@
nno <silent> '##    :<C-U>set opfunc=<SID>op_list_digit
                    \<Bar>exe 'norm! ' . v:count1 . 'g@_'<CR>
xno <silent> '#     :call <SID>op_list_digit()<CR>
```

---

It also works from visual mode.
Ex commands are good for scripting, but for an interactive use, a normal operator is probably better, because you can combine it with any motion or text-object.

For example, you could toggle a list prefixed with asterisks or minus signs inside the current paragraph by hitting `'*ip`. Here, `'*` is an operator and `ip` is the text-object on which it works.

And do the same thing for a list prefixed with numbers across the next 10 lines by hitting `'#10j`. Here, `'#` is another operator and `10j` is a motion covering the lines on which the operator works.

The other benefit of using a custom operator, is that you can repeat your last edition with the dot command.

[image]